# Is it necessary to use JSNI to implement a custom tooltip in an GWT app (or a popup is enought)?

Tags: gwt, popup, tooltip

I would like to have a popup like this site when my mouse hover a movie : http://www.allmovie.com/

This little popup will contain a google map...Can you give me a good solution to do this ? I do not know if using JSNI will slow the app, or simply if it should be easiest to do it with a simple gwt-popup ?

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSNI will not slow down your app.

For a rich tooltip like that, there are widget toolkits that already exist. For example, see: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#tooltips.

Comment: but I will not use SENCHA api....so I need to do it with GWT, I could do it with a popup panel I think.... ?

Comment: It's not an API, it's  a collection of widgets, and they are good-looking and well-tested. But using `PopupPanel` and setting its contents with `setWidget()` seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Ok, actually, my problem is to position the popupPanel just near the poster (the image of the movie). I have difficulties to do that, maybe you can give me information, I tried "setPosition", "showRelativeTo", "setPopupPositionAndShow" but I have doing some spagetties in my code. Tks again ++

Comment: You'll have to programmatically determine the position of the widget you want to anchor the popup to. Or, you could just use Sencha's widget like I suggested in my answer and avoid all of this.

Comment: Ok, I need to be sincere, I would like to try to use the setWidget() but I do not understand how ? If setWidget() is a function that add widgets to the popup so I think it is not the solution I am looking for...because I am trying to do the contrary, I mean, I want my poster to be related to a posterPopup (I am using GWTP with MVP and presenters, and I hesitate to add the posterPopupPresenter as an attribute of the posterPresenter class). If too dificult to understand, no matters.